# Fold nested std::future

Tags: c++, c++14, std, future, c++17

I would like to fold a nested `std::future`, e.g.

```
void foo(std::future<int>)
{
}

foo(fold(std::declval<std::future<std::future<std::shared_future<int>>>>());
```

This is what I've unsucessfully tried so far. It seems to have problems specifically with `std::future<void>` variants.

Any suggestions?

```
#include <future>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

namespace detail {

template <typename T>
auto get(T&& f)
{
    return f;
}

auto get(std::future<void>&& f)
{
    return f.wait();
}

auto get(std::shared_future<void> f)
{
    return f.wait();
}

template <typename T>
auto get(std::future<T>&& f)
{
    return detail::get(f.get());
}

template <typename T>
auto get(std::shared_future<T> f)
{
    return detail::get(f.get());
}

}

template <typename T>
auto fold(T&& f)
{
    return std::async(std::launch::deferred, [f = std::move(f)]() mutable
    {
        return detail::get(f.get());
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you say something about usage? OR just specify what exaclty does not work as expected (does not compile)? Right now, the question is a little unclear to me

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
template <typename T>
auto fold(T&& x)
{
    return x;
}

template <typename T>
auto fold(std::future<T>&& f)
{
    return fold(f.get());
}

template <>
auto fold(std::future<void>&& f)
{
    return f.get();
}
```

Test case:

```
auto r0 = fold(std::future<std::future<std::future<int>>>{
    std::async(std::launch::async, [] {
        return std::async(std::launch::async, [] {
            return std::async(std::launch::async, [] { return 0; });
        });
    })});
fold(std::future<std::future<std::future<void>>>{
    std::async(std::launch::async, [] {
        return std::async(std::launch::async, [] {
            return std::async(std::launch::async, [] { return; });
        });
    })});
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vKeUl0gYPxangwAT)

Comment: Needs a `std::async(std::launch::deferred` or it will return a value not a future.

Comment: @ronag: no, the launch policy does not change the return type.

Comment: Drop the `std::future<std::future<std::future<int>>>` it isn't needed.

Comment: `auto fold(T&& x)` isn't quite right.  Pass an lvalue `future` to `fold` and that overload is called, when that probably isn't what you want.  Also, `shared_future` is missing.